# Rails 3 - overwriting routes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, overwrite

I'm currently having some problems with setting up the right routes for my application.

In short I would like to have URLs like so:

**explanation:**
*`Show actual page for the selected poll`*
**abstract:**
`localhost:3000/polls/:category_slug/:poll_id`
**example:**
 
`localhost:3000/polls/technology/1337` 
**routes.rb**
`get 'polls/:category_slug/:poll_id' => 'polls#show',  :as => :poll`

Furthermore the user should be able to filter the polls against some criteria, like *show Top-Polls, New-Polls* and so on... 
**explanation:** 
*`Show a list of polls, which are matching the selected criteria`*
**abstract:** 
`localhost:3000/polls/:category_slug/:filter_mode` 
 
**example:** 
`localhost:3000/polls/technology/top` 
 
**routes.rb**
`get 'polls/:category_slug/:filter_mode' => 'filter#by_mode', :as => :polls_filter`

And here's the problem
**`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound : Couldn't find Poll with ID=top_all`**

 
The second route (`'polls/:category_slug/:filter_mode'`) is overwriting the first route so Rails recognizes the `:filter_mode` as a `:poll_id`. 
 

So my question is, how can I change this behavior, so **both routes will actually work 
without overwriting each other ?** (the first route will work perefectly, when I leave out the second one)

I hope someone understands my problem, appreciate every help.

Comment: Why don't you use searchlogic or other gem that offers similiar functionality and pass filter criteria in params, without touching routes?

Comment: I didn't use a gem, because I need URLs like described above (e.g. polls/technology/top, which returns me a list of the top polls in the technology category). My approach is to use links (which are calling my filter-controller) for the filtering process, and no search forms (which are passing filter criteria like this "?category=1" in the URL). Unfortunately I wasn't able to figure out, how to do create such URLs with the searchlogic gem, so I decided to do it this way ^^

Comment: Thanks for satisfying my curiosity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a constraint on the filter one to take only strings, and then put it before the other one. It will fall through to the poll_id one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Works like it should now.